# Extract value from url in php

Tags: php, url, substr, strpos

I've a URL similar to this:

```
http://somethinfs.com/folder/134039/the_title_of_somethings.html
http://somethinfs.com/folder/184738/the_title_of_somethings_else.html
```

From this URL, I need to extract the "134039" and "184738".
I've tried to use the strpos and substr but it doesn't work, it just return me `.html`.

Comment: You need regular expressions!

Comment: no the url are of external service, dinamically posted

Answer (score 7):

A mixture of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) would do it.

```
$a = parse_url("http://somethinfs.com/folder/184738/the_title_of_somethings_else.html");
$b = explode("/", $a['path']);
echo $b[2];
```

Output is `184738`

Answer (score 4):

Behold [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info/):

```
if (preg_match('!/(\d+)/!', $url, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

explode link /

```
http:/ /somethinfs.com/folder/134039/the_title_of_somethings.html
 0    1      2           3      4               5
```

so...

```
$tmp = explode('/', $url);
$your_id = $tmp[4];
```

Also you can use regexp as deceze said :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but returns all numbers:

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', "http://somethinfs.com/folder/134039/the_title_of_somethings.html");
echo $number ;
```

Comment: thanks this also work; but what if i need to extract letters?